# Python 2.5 change list and tuple

Tags: list, tuples, python-2.5

The first part of the code works which I believe is changing the list loading into loafing. But the second part of the code which I was given to turn the tuple, loading into loafing  does not.

```
y=['l','o','a','d','i','n','g']

print type(y)

y[3] = 'F'

print y


x=('l','o','a','d','i','n','g')

print type(x)

x[3]='F'

print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuples, like strings, are immutable sequence types--they cannot be changed once created. See [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) on this topic.

Comment: So is it impossible to change the bottom tuple to loafing at all? Is there any trick to get it to say "loafing"? Or any combination with the list above that can change the tuple?

Comment: You'd have to make a copy of the tuple. You can make a copy that is a list with the [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) built-in function.

Comment: oh ok. I see now, what is the semicolon represent again in python?